# Reduce image collection to annual maximum in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, climate

I want to control my NDVI trends with climate variables. Therefore I am using temperature, precipitation and soil moisture. But since my NDVI is in annual maximum I need to have the same format for the controlling. Therefore I try to calculate these annual max images for the climate bands. But when I then try to use these, the analysis is not working and giving me this error:
**Error in map(ID=1): Element.getNumber: Unable to cast value to Number.**

This is the code to calculate the annual max images.

```
//Calc annual max for TerraClimate for Temp, soil and prec
var annual_max_temp =  ee.ImageCollection(ee.List.sequence(1981, 2015).map(function (year){
  var date_start = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
  var date_end = date_start.advance(1, "year");

  return(ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE')
        .select(['tmmx','soil', 'pr'])
        .filterDate(date_start, date_end)
          .max()
          .set({year: year, 'system:time_start':date_start})
          .set({year: year, 'system:time_end':date_end}));
}));
```

And here is the complete code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fwelp1992%2FMaster%3ATemperature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error does not occur in the part of the code you present here. Later, you try to retrieve the `system:time_start` property with `getNumber()`, while you have set it as an `ee.Date()` in line 12. Probably, setting it to the standard GEE long number format (using `millis()` on an `ee.Date()`) will help you:

```
      .set({year: year, 'system:time_start':date_start.millis()})
      .set({year: year, 'system:time_end':date_end.millis()}))
```

Comment: Yes it makes sense. I added the `millis()` now and partly the code works now. But there is still a problem with the feature collection. One of the features (number 137) is not working, but nothing appears to be different. The code works when I limit the FeatureCollection:
`var conflicts = ee.FeatureCollection('users/welp1992/Conflicts25_Date').limit(136)`

Comment: Ask a new question and share your asset to allow others to reproduce the error

Comment: I asked a new question now and shared the FC and script there. 

[Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366934/feature-causing-error-in-climate-linear-regression-analysis)